# MFMailComposeViewController is not presenting itself correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am having a trouble using MFMailComposeViewController.

When I click on a button, an instance of MFMailComposeViewController should present itself:

http://postimg.org/image/i24gn4oi7/

But when it does, this happens:

http://postimg.org/image/kdwm0isrl/

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)actionEmailComposer {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSMutableArray *email = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"factto@gmail.com", nil];

    [mc setToRecipients:email];
    //[mc setSubject:@"SUBJECT_HERE"];
    [mc setMessageBody:@"Referência: \nCor:" isHTML:NO];
    mc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            UIAlertView *msg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Obrigado!" message:@"Logo logo entraremos em contato!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [msg show];
        }
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Actually, on the iPad it does work properly, it just happens on the iPhone!
What is going on? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me understand your question..Is that you want the controller to appear as in image http://postimg.org/image/i24gn4oi7/, but when you click its appearing as http://postimg.org/image/kdwm0isrl/...
Is that your question..

Comment: No, when I try to open the MFMailComposeViewController, it does not work correctly, the view where it opens from, stays in the front, when it should be pushed to the back. Got it? :D @Sabby

Answer (score 0):

The view controller that you present the mail view controller from needs to be full screen and at the front, if it isn't some parts of the view won't respond properly to touches and / or be properly visible (as you see).

Comment: But it's the same code for iPad and iPhone. Why it works on iPad and does not on iPhone? It's really bizarre. It should not be happening!

Comment: Modal presentation on iPhone and iPad is handled very differently, you can see the difference on the screen

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But can you help me work this out? Is anything wrong on my code?

Comment: Present the mail view controller from the window root view controller.